# What does 'PYVERNODOTS' in Python C-extension modules mean?

Tags: python, python-c-api

When I want to compile Python C-extension modules on Linux, the file name of the compiled modules is for example `<name-of-module>.cpython-@PYVERNODOTS@m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. However this only happens, when I compile for Python 3.7, in Python 3.6 the file name is `<name-of-module>.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.
The problem is, that Python 3.7 is unable to import the module with `PYVERNODOTS` in the file name, so here are my questions:
What does `PYVERNODOTS` mean? How can I fix the import issue?

EDIT:

I tested this on Ubuntu with Python 3.7.4 from Anaconda. The complete setup script is hosted at https://github.com/biotite-dev/biotite/blob/master/setup.py.

Comment: 36 is the Python version without dots of Python 3.6 Seems to be something wrong with Python 3.7. Maybe you should give details about how you compile the Python C-extension modules on your Linux (and details about your Linux), so the problem becomes reproducible.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest Python version available from Anaconda, i.e. 3.7.4-h265db76_1, and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Python 3.7.4. Running the compilation under Python 3.7.3 fixed this problem.